# Sails.js Mandrill api error

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sails.js, mandrill

I'm using the ***sails-mandrill*** module for a `sails.js` app. I'm having trouble sending the email. I keep getting this error:

`to` must be specified, e.g.:

```
{ to: { email: "foo@bar.com", name: "Mr. Foo Bar" } }
```

I have my code formatted exactly like that and can't figure out why its still giving me the error.

```js
var email = require('sails-mandrill');
  var recipients = [{
    email: 'name@email.com',
    name: 'John Smith'
  }];
  email.send({
    to: recipients,
    subject: 'Test Email',
    html: 
      'I can\'t wait to see you all in Chicago<br/>' +
      'I loe you so much!!!! ',
    text: 'text fallback goes here-- in case some recipients (let\'s say the Chipettes)  can\'t receive HTML emails'
  }, function optionalCallback (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [API Logs](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/api) in your Mandrill account? If the error is being returned by Mandrill, you can double check there to see the exact JSON that Mandrill is receiving. I'm not familiar with the sails module, but looking at what's being received would give you some additional info.

Comment: I checked the Mandrill API Logs and I don't have any failed API calls, nor do I have any successful API calls. Still confused on this.

Comment: you could just use `nodemailer` and write your own service file to do this for you, i've worked with the mandrill adapter before and didn't like it. You can see this gist here of how im doing email in my sailsjs app.. I do it in the controller, but you could abstract it out to a service. https://gist.github.com/mikedevita/8635763

Comment: The code you've posted above doesn't actually include how you're declaring the recipients, just the variable. If the API call isn't shown in your Mandrill account, it's possible that the sails module is catching an error before you're actually making the call. You may want to check how that handles errors and if the verbiage of the error matches what should be generated by that module.

Comment: After playing around with the code a little bit, I just decided to use the nodemailer module. Much easier to work with I think.